# Pairing with CSR BLE 4.0 dongle

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluez

I have a CSR4.0 BLE dongle I am using in Raspberry Pi. I am using Bluez stack in the Pi and can make the dongle up & running. Now, when I use some iOS app (LightBlue) to find out nearby BLE devices, most of the time it can't find the CSR device.

A few times the app can find the CSR device, but when I press CSR name in the app, the app tries to connect to the CSR dongle but fails. Then the dongle becomes invisible.

Any thought on why this happens? How can I reliably find the CSR dongle? And how can I connect to it? Do I need to write some BLE application code to run on the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to advertise a BLE service on the Pi so LightBlue can discover it from your iPhone.

One way to do this is to create a service on the Raspberry Pi using [Bleno](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno). Try the [battery-service example](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno/tree/master/examples/battery-service).